# Applying 'AND' to all items between two lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections of different types:

```
// First Collection
public class ObjectA
{
   public IEnumerable<SomeObject> Persons { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SomeOtherObject> Items { get; set; }
}

public class SomeObject
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
}
public class SomeOtherObject
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
}

// Second Collection (ID property holds unique values, PersonID and EntityID do not)
public class ObjectB
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string PersonID { get; set; }
    public string EntityID{ get; set; }
}

// Assuming the following entries...
var list1 = new ObjectA();
var persons = new List<SomeObject>();
persons.Add(new SomeObject() { ID = "A" });
persons.Add(new SomeObject() { ID = "B" });
persons.Add(new SomeObject() { ID = "C" });
list1.Persons = persons;

var items = new List<SomeOtherObject>();
items.Add(new SomeOtherObject() { ID = "1" });
items.Add(new SomeOtherObject() { ID = "2" });
list1.Items = items;

var list2 = new List<ObjectB>();
list2.Add(new ObjectB() { ID = "1", PersonID = "C", EntityID = "1" });
list2.Add(new ObjectB() { ID = "2", PersonID = "A", EntityID = "1" });
list2.Add(new ObjectB() { ID = "3", PersonID = "A", EntityID = "2" });
list2.Add(new ObjectB() { ID = "4", PersonID = "B", EntityID = "1" });
list2.Add(new ObjectB() { ID = "5", PersonID = "B", EntityID = "2" });
```

Given these two lists (list1, and list2). How do I find items in list2 where
PersonID = A AND B
AND 
EntityID = 1 AND 2

In other words, all conditions must be met so 'Person C' wouldn't make it because they only have EntityID = "1", not both "1" and "2"

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for a LINQ query? i.e. you don't want to foreach through these lists and keep track of matches.

Comment: How can `EntityID` be `"1"` **and** `"2"`? Did you mean `"1"` **or** `"2"`?

Comment: And what is the use of `list1` in your code?

Comment: @JRoughan - Hi. Yes, that's correct I would like to use linq. I'm trying to avoid the ugly way.

Comment: @DominicKexel - No, I did mean "1" **and** "2"

Comment: I can see what you mean by `EntityID = 1 AND 2`, i.e. `list2` has entries for the same `PersonID` with both `EntityID`s, but I don't see how you can logically work `PersonID = A AND B` into the same idea.

Comment: @Rawling - I know. I'm having trouble conceptualizing it too. Hence my post. In the end, I only want items from list2 where the IDs are 2, 3, 4, and 5. Not 1.

Comment: They are lists of different types... Also, `ObjectB` does not contain an `EntityID`..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - Exactly.

Comment: Maybe I need to make two separate lists from list2, one for the PersonIDs, another for the EntityIDs and then do an if statement like: if (PersonIDs.All(e => list2.Any(a => a.PersonID == e.ID) && EntityIDs.All(f => list2.Any(b => b.EntityID == f.ID)) ???

Comment: This won't compile since `Persons` is a `IEnumerable<SomeObject>` which doesn't have an `Add` method even if you initialize it with a `List<SomeObject>`. Then you need to cast it accordingly.

Comment: Example updated to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the question right, this query will give you all the person IDs that contain ALL the EntityIds listed in list1.Items (rather than hard-coding 1 & 2)

```
var validIds = list1.Items.Select(i => i.ID);
var validPersonIds = list2.GroupBy(p => p.PersonID)
                          .Where(g => validIds.All(i => g.Any(x => x.EntityID == i)))
                          .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Update: From your comment, I think this is what you need. It returns the objects from list2 with the IDs 2, 3, 4 and 5

```
var validEntityIds = list1.Items.Select(i => i.ID);
var validPersonIds = list1.Persons.Select(i => i.ID);
var validObjects = list2.GroupBy(p => p.PersonID)
                        .Where(g => validPersonIds.Contains(g.Key) &&
                                    validEntityIds.All(i => g.Any(x => x.EntityID == i)))
                        .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Comment: If you wanted to return the actual object, just modify the `Select` and if you wanted to return the matches from list1.Persons you would just need a `Where` query on that list using the ids from this query.

Comment: I'm not following. This gives me two separate lists which in effect I already know by looking at the list1.Persons and list2.Items collections. I need to bring back list2 items for IDs 2, 3, 4, and 5

Comment: NB The newer version creates three collections, but only as an optimisation. If you really want a one-liner you can replace the variables in the last query (validObjects) with the inlined sub-queries but leaving them out seems easier to read and more performant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
list2.Where(b => list1.Persons.Exists(person => person.ID == b.PersonID) &&
                 list1.Items.TrueForAll(id => list2.Exists(bs => bs.EntityID == id.ID && bs.PersonID == b.PersonID)))
```

This will give 4 items from list2 (and you can take unique Persons, if you want)

Comment: Ah, this looks very promising. I will try it out and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: To me this query returns nothing :(

Comment: You're right. Extis and TrueForAll does not exist. What library are these extension methods referenced from?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I`ve changed IEnumerable from your example to Lists, and those methods are for List

Comment: That explains it. I'll give it try but I think @JRoughan beat you to the punch. Aside from creating lists this seems very elegant.

Comment: Well I used List as IEnumerable does not have Add, as Tim Schmelter  already mentioned.

Comment: Your answer is correct as well. I tried it and this works: list2.Where(b => list1.Persons.ToList().Exists(person => person.ID == b.PersonID) &&
                 list1.Items.ToList().TrueForAll(id => list2.ToList().Exists(bs => bs.EntityID == id.ID && bs.PersonID == b.PersonID))); but has a worse performance factor than @JRoughan's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This gives you the combinations you want.

```
        var listSelected = (from val2 in list2
                            where val2.PersonID == "A" || val2.PersonID == "B"
                            && val2.EntityID == "1" || val2.EntityID == "2"
                            select val2).ToList();
```

Comment: Hmm. I need a generic way to do it since I can't hard code "A", "B", "1", "2", etc...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this produce what you want:

```
  var result1 = list2.Where(row=> row.EntityID=="1").Select(r=>r.PersonID);
  var result2 = list2.Where(row => row.EntityID == "2").Select(r => r.PersonID);
  var finalResult = result1.Intersect(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
list2.Where(p => p.EntityID == "1" || p.EntityID == "2")
    .GroupBy(p => p.PersonID)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() == 2);
```

This will return each person from `list2` that has entities 1 and 2 specified; so "A" and "B" from your example data.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment to Azhar, the following is more generic:

```
var entityFilter = new string[]{"1", "2"};

list2.Where(p => entityFilter.Contains(p.EntityID))
    .GroupBy(p => p.PersonID)
    .Where(grp => grp.Count() == entityFilter.Count());
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll be trying out everyone's answer in the order they were received shortly and will update the post to let everyone know which one works best for my situation.

Comment: This is close but it skips items 3 and 5. Here's my test:                             foreach (var item in query)
            {
                var ob = item.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
                Console.WriteLine(ob.ID);
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = list2.GroupBy(item => item.PersonID)
                 .Where(g => g.Any(item => item.EntityID == "1") &&
                             g.Any(item => item.EntityID == "2"))
                 .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Returns all items except first one, because there is not items with PersonID equal to `C` which have EntityID equal to 1 and 2.